# How to modify entity manager's query cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching

clearing the entire query cache is really expensive in my situation so I would like to clear only a specific query cache.

Say I have performed the following hql query:

```
SELECT FROM Car c WHERE c.id = 22
```

In the next time, I would like to force hibernate to fetch the result from the database instead of getting what is in the query cache.

Observations: Neither turning off the query caching nor clearing the entire cache are valid options. I can not compromise the performance at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable caching on query using `hibernateQuery.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH)`.

Programmatic invalidation:

Set region name when creating query `hibernateQuery.setCacheRegion("car22")` and then invalidate it `session.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictQueryRegion("car22");`